# Keep permanent IP for ingress-nginx (and using kustomize)

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize, ingress-nginx

**Problem**

On a fresh Kubernetes cluster, I want to configure an nginx ingress with a public IP that remains stable, regardless of later changes to the nginx ingress controller; ie. I want to be able to delete and restore the ingress without changes to the IP address; the IP address is handed out by my Kubernetes provider.

There is an inspiring guide on [github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/static-ip); however, the solution is very handcrafted and does not tell how to do it with automation tools like `helm` or `kustomize`.

I want (1) to use [ingress-nginx](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx), which installs via `helm`, (2) to have the public IP stable, regardless of `helm (un)install`, and (3) to use [kustomize](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/).

**Question**

I have isolated my `kustomize` configuration on a [branch here on github](https://github.com/defaultbranch/personal-infra-on-k8s/tree/question-how-to-configure-static-ingress-ip/kustomization/base), three files. (If I better could/should provide this otherwise, let me know.)

When I apply this, it creates two `LoadBalancer` endpoints, instead of a single one; ingress-nginx is not using the `public-static-ip` service's endpoint, but launches its own.

How do I have to change the kustomization so it picks up the helm chart but also uses the `public-static-ip` service's endpoint?